# App.xaml.cs UnhandledException when Binding Image URL in Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, binding

i have this XAML

```
(...)
<ListBox Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,-20,0" x:Name="post_Images_Grid_list" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#FF#247722" Margin="0,0,10,20">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding image, Mode=OneWay}" Width="110" Height="110" Margin="5" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox> 
(...)
```

And this C# Code in MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
(...)
post_Images_Grid_list.ItemsSource = thePost.images;
(...)
```

The definition of thePost.images:

```
public List<BitmapImages> images = new List<BitmapImages>();
```

And the BitmapImages class:

```
public class BitmapImages
{
    public BitmapImage image { get; set; }

    public BitmapImages(string image_url)
    {
        this.image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image_url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

But after xaml page display completed, debug jump to method **Application_UnhandledException** in **App.xaml.cs**, what is the problem?

Here is the data of List images at run time:

[image: Data of List]

Everything looks right to me! Each URL exists and has an image, I checked in web browser.

I appreciate your help, I have no idea what's going on!.

Thank you,Rohit Vats, here is the e.Exception:

- e.ExceptionObject   {MS.Internal.WrappedException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ---> System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
  at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
  at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
  at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
  at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WrapPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.Exception {MS.Internal.WrappedException}

It seems it has to do with the size of the xaml image element?

Comment: Post error message here you are getting.

Comment: > MSFTInsider.DLL!MSFTInsider.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender = {MSFTInsider.App}, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e = {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}) Línea 127 C#

Comment: Debugger.Break() in App.xaml.cs. There is no exception in the app code

Comment: Debugger breaks in App.xaml.cs because there is some error which is not handled and makes its ways to Unhandled exception method. Check `e.Exception` for the error message.

Comment: Added to the question, too long for comments.

Comment: Error seems to be originating from third party control. Are you using any third party control in your XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i feel stupid:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#FF#247722" (...) />
```

Copypaste error here:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#FF247722" (...) />
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that there is a problem with your XAML that couldn't be validated at design time but would manifest in runtime. Given your scenario I'm guessing the row you're adding may cause one of the Datagrid column templates to error in this manner.

This usually is due to a reference to a style or an event handler that does not exist or is not within the context of the XAML. In my experience this is a common occurence in Custom Control development.

You should remove the the Styles from the control, and it will be handled confirmly.